# JAVA what line does the character(s) appear in

Tags: java

So I've been playing around with getting java to accept an input file and then analyze that file and return something.  Currently, I am trying to get it to accept a file directory, read that file, then ask the user for a character or string of characters to search for.  It then searches that file for those characters, and then outputs the amount of times that character(s) have appeared, and on what lines they've appeared on.  I've seen similar projects on StackedOverflow, and combined a few of them to get a partially working code.  The following code however does not output the lines that the string was on, just total lines in the file.

How would I get this to output the lines that the string was found on?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class assign6 {
public static int countLines(String filename) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
    try {
        byte[] c = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        int readChars = 0;
        boolean empty = true;
        while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
            empty = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
                if (c[i] == '\n') {
                    ++count;
                }
            }
        }
        return (count == 0 && !empty) ? 1 : count;
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        boolean play = false;
        while (play == false) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Full File Directory:");
        String filePath = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Character or String of Characters to search for:");
        String testString = s.nextLine();

        String strLine;
        int numRead=0;

        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                strLine = strLine + " ";
                String [] strArry = strLine.split(testString);

                if (strArry.length > 1) {
                     numRead = numRead + strArry.length - 1;
                }
                else {
                     if (strLine == testString) {
                         numRead++;
                     }
                }
            }

            in.close();

            System.out.println(testString + " was found " + numRead + " times.");
            System.out.println(countLines(filePath));

        }catch (Exception e){
        }
        System.out.println(" Do you want to play again: 1 for yes, 2 for no");
        Scanner z = new Scanner(System.in);
        int playagain;
        playagain = z.nextInt();
        if (playagain == 1) {
            play = false;
        }else{
            if (playagain == 2){
                play = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ You are asking for us to debug your program, which is pretty inefficient when you can try it yourself.

Comment: Well, if your count is working, you know how to find the lines, so print line number when that occurs. It really is that simple.